# Caliburn.micro design time data for WinRT - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro, design-time, design-time-data

I'm doing windows 8 app dev using the caliburn.micro MVVM framework.

I'm having issues with design time data. I've looked high and low through various blogs and what not to find an answer. No luck so far.

Here is a section from my view where I say use this view model for design time

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:cal="using:Caliburn.Micro"  
xmlns:vm="using:MyApp.SampleViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:SampleNewsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
cal:Bind.AtDesignTime="True">
```

The d:DataContext... part is being underlined and saying "**object reference not set to an instance of an object**"

I have a view model with a default constructor

```
namespace MyApp.SampleViewModels
{
   public sealed class SampleNewsViewModel 
   {
       public SampleNewsViewModel()
       {
           Title = "News Title";
       }

       private string _title;
       public string Title
       {
           get { return _title; }
           set { _title = value; }
       }
   }
}
```

Pretty sure there's nothing wrong with my ViewModel (but I could be wrong).
I can't figure this out, any point in the right direction would be awesome.

cheers,
Lochana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man...I found the issue, and it's my fault.

In my design time view model, I **had not initialized the list**, and in the constructor, was trying to add  items to it.

This fixed it

```
private List<NewsItem> _itemListView = new List<NewsItem>();
    public List<NewsItem> ItemListView
    {
        get { return _itemListView; }
        set { _itemListView = value; }             
    }
```

The lesson I learned here is that the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" can mean you're **view model is broken**, even though it doesn't explicitly say. So for anyone starting out with caliburn.micro, **unit test your design time view models** to make sure they work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have got the namespaces configured correctly *(this gives me a headache many times)*. Now with that out of our way, i can tell you to try too things:

1. Try to add these to your namespace declarations `mc:Ignorable="d"` and `xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`.
2. If this alone didn't work then try to replace
   `Type=vm:SampleNewsViewModel` with `Type={x:Type
   vm:SampleNewsViewModel` and see if it works.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I should have pasted all my namespace declarations. I already had those up there.

As for point number 2, just to clarify, did you mean replace it with Type={x:Type vm:SampleNewsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true} ? What I want to clarify is, is there meant to be a space between x:Type and vm:SampleNews...?

Comment: @LochanaWijesundera yes there should be a space.

Comment: I figured it out, it was my fault. My xaml was fine, it was my view model that was broken. I should have unit tested.

Comment: @LochanaWijesundera great, so problem is fixed.